# Alternative Windows 10 password

Tags: password-recovery

A friend not comfortable with computers has run into a problem. As I understand it, her computer is set up to require a local account password, but has stopped recognising her local account password. I've found on the Web suggestions as to how overcome her problem, but I'm afraid implementing any of them would be beyond her. She's also self-isolating, so can't take her computer anywhere or have anyone come to her.

It occurred to me that a possible solution that wouldn't be beyond her would be for her to create a Microsoft account (using her mobile phone) and then enter her new Microsoft account password when prompted for a Windows password on her computer.

Would that work?

Thanks,

Leslie

Comment: What you describe requires access to the user profile which you indicate is not possible; So your idea absolutely will not work.  Your friend will have to take it to somebody.

Comment: If she (thinks she) knows the password, make sure its not something simple like a caps lock or num lock problem.  Suggest using the on screen keyboad to enter the password.